# COUNT(field) returns correct amount of rows but full SELECT query returns zero rows

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a UDF in my database which basically tries to get a station (e.g. bus/train) based on some input data (geographic/name/type). Inside this function i try to check if there are any rows matching the given values:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(s.id) 
INTO 
    firsttry 
FROM 
    geographic.stations AS s
WHERE 
    ST_DWithin(s.the_geom,plocation,0.0017) 
AND 
    s.name <-> pname < 0.8 
AND 
    s.type ~ stype;
```

The *firsttry* variable now contains the value 1. If i use the following (slightly extended) SELECT statement i get no results:

```
RETURN query SELECT
        s.id, s.name, s.type, s.the_geom,
        similarity(
            regexp_replace(s.name::text,'(Hauptbahnhof|Hbf)','Hbf'),
            regexp_replace(pname::text,'(Hauptbahnhof|Hbf)','Hbf')
        )::double precision AS sml,
        st_distance(s.the_geom,plocation) As dist from geographic.stations AS s
    WHERE ST_DWithin(s.the_geom,plocation,0.0017) and s.name <-> pname < 0.8 
    AND s.type ~ stype
    ORDER BY dist asc,sml desc LIMIT 1;
```

the parameters are as follows:

```
stype = '^railway'
pname = 'Amsterdam Science Park'
plocation = ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(4.9492530 52.3531670)')
```

the tuple i need to be returned is:

```
id     name                    type              geom (displayed as ST_AsText)
909658;"Amsterdam Sciencepark";"railway_station";"POINT(4.9482893 52.352904)"
```

The same UDF returns quite well for a lot of other stations, but this is one (of more) which just won't work. Any suggestions?

P.S. The use of the **<->** operator is coming from the [pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) module.

Comment: If you take that select statement and issue it directly in a psql prompt manually substituting the parameters does it work? If so then you will need to show the function definition.

Comment: A question like this *requires* the function definition and the version numbers of Postgres & PostGis, of course. Ideally a test case to reproduce, too.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas on how to troubleshoot this:

1. Break your troubleshooting into steps.  Start with the simplest query possible.  No aggregates, just joins and no filters.  Then add filters.  Then add order by, then add aggregates.  Look at exactly where the change occurs.
2. Try reindexing the database.

One possibility that occurs to me based on this is that it could be a corrupted index used in the second query but not the first.  I have seen corrupted indexes in the past and usually they throw errors but at least in theory they should be able to create a problem like this.

If this is correct, your query will suddenly return rows if you remove the ORDER BY clause.

If you have a corrupted index, then you need to pay close attention to hardware.  Is the RAM ECC?  Is the processor overheating?  How are you disks doing?

A second possibility is that there is a typo on a join condition of filter statement.  Normally this is something I would suspect first but it is easy enough to weed out index problems to start there.  If removing the ORDER BY doesn't change things, then chances are it is a typo.  If you can't find a typo, then try reindexing.